# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) is keeping me from finishing my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i am trying to make a dictionary from a file in python and i keep getting this error. I have no idea how to fix it. Help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
 dict = {}
 f = open('example.txt', 'r')
 row = f.read()
 lines = row.split("\n")
 for line in lines:
     name, number = line.split(")")
     dict[name] = number
 f.close()
 return dict
```

And here is how the file looks like:

```
a)b
b)c
abc)d
d)dac
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either remove the empty line from the end of the file (and yes, it is there), or add `if line:` check before splitting on `)` or actually check the length of `line.split(')')` because your code will break anyway every time a line with less or more than one `)` is present

Comment: ```line.split(")")``` This line produced only one value

Comment: Check if you have extra empty line in the file. And don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's a built in name.

Comment: Hmm. `return dict` out side of the function?

Comment: sorry i forgot to select the name of the function when i copied it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**read** will add an extra blank line when it hits the end of the file.
*To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string or bytes object. size is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at most size bytes are read and returned. If the end of the file has been reached, f.read() will return an empty string ('').*

change your program to check if libe exists.

```
dict = {}
f = open('example.txt', 'r')
row = f.read()
lines = row.split("\n")
for line in lines:
   if line:
      name, number = line.split(")")
      dict[name] = number
f.close()
return dict
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

IMP: please do not use builtin name dict for a variable

Answer (score 1):

you are getting an empty line by the last `row.split`. You can remove it as follows by checking for `if line`:

`lines = [line for line in row.split("\n") if line]`

In addition you shouldn't reuse the builtin name dict for a variable. And you are using return outside a function, which is invalid.

Comment: I would actually check `if ')' in line` to make sure that it doesn't fail in case of other lines that do not have a `)`. Also, `readlines` would be better than `read` and then splitting by `\n`.